# Pacemaker Cluster Issue - Backup Firewall does not take over in case network cable unplugged from Primary Firewall

Tags: high-availability, failovercluster, drbd, pacemaker, corosync

I have an issue with pacemaker cluster.

I have two firewalls that I am using in Active/ Backup HA. The heartbeat IPs are `10.0.0.1` (FW 1) & `10.0.0.2` (FW 2) on a dedicated network. Traffic IPs on LAN network are `131.107.2.2` (FW 1), `131.107.2.3` (FW 2) and virtual IP is `131.107.2.101`. Traffic IPs on WAN network are `192.168.100.98` (FW 1), `192.168.100.99` (FW 2) and virtual IP is `192.168.100.101`.

If FW 1 is powered off, FW 2 takes over as intended but if the network cable is removed on LAN network, the switching does not happen. Following components are being used in the cluster:

- pacemaker
- corosync
- drbd
- contrackd

  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the direct connection between the two firewalls? Or the LAN connection to your internal network?

Comment: Show your config.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Pacemaker you care about interfaces failing. Look at the ocf:pacemaker:ping resource. You can use that resource-agent to ping other host (defined with `host_list` param) on the different networks, and Pacemaker will react if those pings fail.

If you group the ocf:pacemaker:ping resources, or use constraints to relate them with whatever else you're managing in Pacemaker, they'll all move together.